# In general, when programming API interactions, should I end the base url with a slash?

Tags: httprequest

This question isn't specific to any particular library, framework, or programming langauge, because I expect this to be a sort of generalized rule that has a standard answer across all, or most, programming disciplines.

Imagine I'm writing a class to interact with some Rest api. The rest api has endpoints like this:

```
POST www.rest.com/item/create
POST www.rest.com/item/delete
POST www.rest.com/schedule/add
GET  www.rest.com/schedule/{user-id}
```

Now, in my class to interact with this api, naturally I'm going to have a base url

```
private string baseUrl = "www.rest.com/";
```

And when I want to make a request, I'm going to append the rest of the route to that base URL.

```
string url = this.baseUrl + "item/delete";
```

My question is, is it standard to include the slash at the end of `rest.com`, or is it standard to leave base url without the slash, `baseUrl = "www.rest.com"`, and put the slash at the start of the route, `this.baseUrl + "/item/delete"`?

I have a feeling there's a universally preferred way, but I can't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: In general - No. 
HTTP servers by default usually cut ending slashes. So request to www.rest.com/item/delete/ will be automatically targeted to www.rest.com/item/delete

Comment: Use the stdlib functions to construct URI instead of glueing strings together. In ruby, for example: `URI.join("https://test.com", "item/delete")`. If your stdlib doesn't have this, then it doesn't matter. Whatever is easier for you to build correct strings. There's no universally preferred way.